# SQL query put nth match in new column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using SQL in Microsoft access. The table may contain more than one value for a bar code. I want to a query that returns one row with each unique bar code and columns for each of the first 5  values. Right now, I have a query returning the last value or the first value with min or max. How can I show the second result in the next column? or the nth result in that column? This is in Access but any other SQL help would be appreciated.

Current table:

[image: current table]

Current query:

```
SELECT table.barcode, MIN(table.value)
FROM table
GROUP BY table.barcode
```

Current output:

[image: current output]

Goal query output:

[image: gola query output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT table.barcode,
       MIN(table.value),
       IIF(MIN(table.value) = MAX(table.value), MAX(table.VALUE), NULL)
FROM table
GROUP BY table.barcode
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will this extend to the 3rd, or 4th value? I should have put that in the tables I pasted in but there may be up to 5 values.

Comment: @MatthewEdmond . . . No.  This answers the question that you asked here.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, if you intend more values.